# Can a Canon MX870 printer be made to work with Windows 98SE?

Tags: windows-98, inkjet-printer

My client's workplace, which is chock full of legacy equipment and software, recently purchased a Canon MX870. Up until now they've been using it for faxes and for printing from the lone piece of recent equipment, a Mac Book. Now they want to hook it into the network. However, all the documentation for this printer says it won't work with anything less than Windows 2000.

As I was installing the driver for this printer (I have one at home now) I noticed that the installer identified the printer as belonging to the MP150 inkjet family. Is it possible that installing the drivers for the MP150 (which are available for Windows 98SE) will make printing to the MX870 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hardware will work with an older driver but results are unpredictable.  It is worth trying but I would think some features will not function or function incorrectly.  Possibly printing only with older driver.

I have made this work for some HP LaserJet hardware.